# Using AjaxExtensions.RouteLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

To address a particular requirement in ASP.net MC3, I wanted to use AjaxExtensions.RouteLink
But I wonder how to use it in a view.
For example:

```
@AjaxExtensions.RouteLink(ajaxHelper, link.Text, new { controller="Home",action="List",
                                                            category = id }, 
                                                            new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "itemList",InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace },
                                                            new { @class = "item" })
```

But while running it throws me error "The name 'ajaxHelper' does not exist in the current context". Since I am new to this usage,it stops me.Could anyone please share some details of using this one ? Thanks much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used something like below instead:

```
@foreach (var link in Model)
{
    if (link.SubCat.Count == 0)
    {    

    @Ajax.RouteLink(link.Text, new
                                    {
                                       controller = "Home",
                                       action = "List",
                                       pId = link.Id,
                                       parentCatId=link.ParentCatId
                                   },

                                    new AjaxOptions
                                    {
                                        UpdateTargetId = "itemList", //div name
                                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
                                    },
                                    new { @class = "menuitem" }
                      )


    }
```

The above code is in a PartialView. But now the problem with this is , it doesn't update the result to the Target provided. Instead it replaces the result to the whole page. Hopefully somebody now can give me a clue to  get rid of this.